# Angular Material highlight simple text with matching color for prebuilt theme

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm using Angular Material components in my project. I'm searching a component, what I can highlight some text on my page with a matching color for a prebuilt theme (I'm using deeppurple-amber.css currently).

I couldn't find any proper solution for this, just this feature request, what is currently opened:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9138

I think I sould do the work for my own, but I don't know how can I select a matching color for the template. I need to define a proper color for this template (I think it's not the best solution)? If this is the only way, how can I select a color?

Or is there a good solution what is "compute" the good color somehow for any template?

Or is there a component, what I didn't find?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you need to get the color of the theme you set and apply it to other components in your view.

You can get the color like:

`myDiv.style.backgroundColor` in your TS file and assign the same color to other components in your view.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and sorry, maybe I was not clear. I need to create something like html 5 <mark> tag, what is highlight a text with a color. But this color should fit for material design principles and my application's base color.